# Incompatible Decimal Element Type For Integer Set

Tags: apex, formula, custom-field

Not understanding issue with code below. The Schedule_Development_*r.YearNumber*_c field is a formula field that returns a number (4,0). Its there to convert a picklist of years such as '2013', '2014' etc into Integers for comparison in Apex.

Keep getting "Incompatible Decimal Element Type For Integer Set" in class below for last line.

> Set years = new Set();//, month = new Set();
>   For(Schedule_Connection__c record : schconnids) {
>   years.add(record.Schedule_Development_*r.YearNumber*_c);

Note: schconnids = List 
I also tried just creating a number field (4,0) in SFDC and getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Had to change last line to

years.add((record.Schedule_Development_r.YearNumber_c).intvalue());

Had tried that but forgot () after intvalue so was getting a compile error!